# wait for a function to run and then start activity

Tags: android, android-activity

When the users presses the start button , a check runs to see if GPS is enabled and then starts an activity.The checkGPS uses alertmanager.

```
case R.id.startbtn:
        checkGPS();
        Intent gpslocation=new Intent(this,selection.class);
        startActivity(gpslocation);
        break;
```

How can I accomplish to wait to the user to enable GPS and then start the activity?

Comment: if you could modify your `checkGPS()` to return a `boolean`, you can check that in a simple `if statement` and proceed only if it returns true. Just something at the top of my mind.

Comment: @Siddharth Lele:The checkGPS() uses alertdialog.builder , so I don't know how to do it boolean..

Comment: How does the method currently function? Does it simply display an Alert if the GPS is not available?

Comment: @Siddharth Lele:Yes, it displays an alert and option to activate manually.

Answer (score 1):

1) in `onCreate()` method, register `LocationListener` on your Activity :

```
   // get location manager
   LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
   Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
   btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, YourActivity.this);
       }
   });
```

2) your activity should implement `LocationListener`:

```
   public class YourActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

3) override methods of `LocationListener` :

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     // when the position has changed
     Log.d(TAG, "location changed.");
}

```
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     // when the source (GSP or GSM network) are disabled
     Log.d(TAG, "the source "+provider+" has been disabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     Log.i(TAG, "the source "+provider+" has been enabled");
     //here you should test if the provider enabled is GPS , if yes , then launch your GPSActivity
     if(provider.equals("gps") {
           Intent gpslocation=new Intent(this,selection.class);
           startActivity(gpslocation);
     }
     else {
           //launch your alert dialog here
     }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
     Log.i(TAG, "source status "+provider+" has been changed to : "+status);
}
```

Comment: :the problem is that i call selection class (which uses the google map) from my main activity by pressing a button, so I can't ? have to implement location listener?

Comment: so in your `onClick` method you will have :  :`lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`and delete it from your `onCreate()` method

Comment: :It says "Cannot refer to a non final variable " for lManager.requestLocationUpdates

Comment: :Isn't there another way to achieve what I want from my main acitvity?(the  code I have in the question).Thanks

Comment: just declare it as a global variable or declare it as `final LocationManager lManager;`

Comment: :Then,it says "the method requestLocationUpdates..is not applicable for the arguments (string,int..) .Isn't another way for that?

Comment: see my edits ,it is just about the this instance refers to the instance of `OnClickListener` , you should change it to `YourActivity.this`

Comment: :Ok, I don't understand how I am going to use my "checkGPS" function now, because in it I have the alert dialog.

Comment: this alertDialog  will display what exactly ??

Comment: :It displays that the GPS is not enable and offers 2 options.Go to enable it (and points to the settings) and cancel.

Comment: :Now it does nothing when i press the start button.The logcat gives me a message(not error) when i press "the source gps has been disabled"

Comment: :Hello , it seems that I had 2 listeners on start button (I forgot the previous I had).Now,when I press start I have my alertdialog and go to the settings for gps.And then immediately my "selection" class where I have the map is starting.But,now , the map is not showing.It gets the coordinates ,but no map.Is some sort of interfering?Also, how can I stop the gps?Thanks a lot!

Comment: :Ok , the problem with the map was that the wi-fi connection was off.So, I need to turn on simultaneously the GPS and Network coonection.Also, when I press the "back" button(arrow),it goes to the settings page.How can I do it to go to the mainactivity?And how can I handle the stop button in order to stop the gps?